# Importing xsd into wsdl

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, wsdl2java

This is my current configuration:

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock"
    xmlns:tns="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"  targetNamespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock">

<xsd:element name="Stock">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ticker" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="quotes" nillable="true" type="Quote"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="Quote">
    ........
</xsd:complexType>
.......
<xsd:element name="gethighBetaStockResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="stock" ref="Stock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

### WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><definitions targetNamespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock/wsdl"
    .....xmlns:external="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock"
<import namespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock" location="Stock.xsd" />
<message name="getStockQuoteResp">
    <part name="parameters" element="external:getStockQuoteResponse" />
</message>
```

However,the moment ref="Stock" is changed to type="Stock",the wsdl2java starts giving 
Type {http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock}Stock is referenced but not defined.

Somehow it seems a clash between wsdl and xsd imports - but I just cant resolve it.Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, the XSD has an issue where an element is both named or referenced; in your case should be referenced.

Change:

```
<xsd:element name="stock" ref="Stock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

To:

```
<xsd:element name="stock" type="Stock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

And:

- Remove the declaration of the global element `Stock`
- Create a complex type declaration for a type named `Stock`

So:

```
<xsd:element name="Stock">
    <xsd:complexType>
```

To:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Stock">
```

Make sure you fix the xml closing tags.

The second problem is that the correct way to reference an external XSD is to use XSD schema with import/include within a wsdl:types element. wsdl:import is reserved to referencing other WSDL files. More information is available by going through the WS-I specification, section [WSDL and Schema Import](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#WSDL_and_Schema_Import). Based on WS-I, your case would be:

**INCORRECT:** (the way you showed it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock/wsdl"
    .....xmlns:external="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock"
    <import namespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock" location="Stock.xsd" />
    <message name="getStockQuoteResp">
        <part name="parameters" element="external:getStockQuoteResponse" />
    </message>
</definitions>
```

**CORRECT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock/wsdl"
    .....xmlns:external="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock"
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock" schemaLocation="Stock.xsd" />             
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getStockQuoteResp">
        <part name="parameters" element="external:getStockQuoteResponse" />
    </message>
</definitions>
```

**SOME** processors may support both syntaxes. The XSD you put out shows issues, make sure you first validate the XSD.

It would be better if you go the WS-I way when it comes to WSDL authoring.

Other issues may be related to the use of relative vs. absolute URIs in locating external content.

Comment: I need to get the following form to work
<xsd:element name="stock" type="Stock" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
Importing both into xsd and wsdl doesnt help
    <import namespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock" location="Stock.xsd" /> 
 <types>
   <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock/wsdl">
   <import namespace="http://stock.com/schemas/services/stock" schemaLocation="Stock.xsd"/>
 </schema>
 
 </types>

Comment: Silly mistake - but appreciate the help in identifying the discrepancy.

Answer (score 12):

**import vs. include**

The primary purpose of an import is to import a *namespace*. A more common use of the XSD import statement is to import a *namespace* which appears in another file. You might be gathering the namespace information from the file, but don't forget that it's the **namespace** that you're importing, **not the file** (don't confuse an `import` statement with an `include` statement).

Another area of confusion is how to specify the location or path of the included `.xsd` file: An XSD import statement has an optional attribute named `schemaLocation` but it is not necessary **if** the namespace of the import statement is at the same location (in the same file) as the import statement itself.

When you do chose to use an external `.xsd` file for your WSDL, the `schemaLocation` attribute becomes necessary. Be very sure that the *namespace* you use in the import statement is the same as the targetNamespace of the schema you are importing. That is, all 3 occurrences must be identical:

**WSDL:**

```
xs:import namespace="urn:listing3" schemaLocation="listing3.xsd"/>
```

**XSD:**

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:listing3"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Another approach to letting know the WSDL about the XSD is through Maven's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources-xmlbeans</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
    <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can read more on this in this [great IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-imports/). It has typos such as `xsd:import` instead of `xs:import` but otherwise it's fine.