# What makes wsdl file with portType but without binding correct?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

In the wsdl [manual](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:binding), in the second section of example 2, There is a wsdl file that has `portType`, but no `binding` blocks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions

             targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote/definitions"
             xmlns:tns="http://example.com/stockquote/definitions"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">


    <import namespace="some.xsd"
            location="some.xsd"/>

    <message name="GetLastTradePriceInput">
        <part name="body"/>
    </message>

    <message name="GetLastTradePriceOutput">
        <part name="body"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="StockQuotePortType">
        <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
            <input message="tns:GetLastTradePriceInput"/>
            <output message="tns:GetLastTradePriceOutput"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
</definitions>
```

`some.xsd` is section 1 of the same example, and contains no bindings, either.

When I try to pass that file through the `wsdltojava` of `cxf`, it gives me a warning

```
 WARNING: WSDL document file:/C:/IdeaProjects/sss/webservices/src/main/schema/BundleAdmin/Atry.wsdl does not define any services
```

and an error:

```
WSI-BP-1.0 R2718 violation: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST have the same set of wsdl:operations as the wsdl:portType to which it refers. GetLastTradePrice not found in wsdl:binding.
```

These are used arguments for `wsdltojava`:

```
                List<String> prepareArgs = ['-fe', 'jaxws',
                                            '-autoNameResolution',
                                            '-db', 'jaxb',
                                            '-xjc-extension',
                                            '-impl', '-server', '-client', '-validate',
                                            '-d', ext.genDirName,
                                            /* change package name for types already generated with XmlBeans */
                                            '-p', 'http://messaging.ei.tmobile.net/datatypes=net.tmobile.ei.messaging.jaxb'
```

Please, what makes the translation program to demand the `binding` section? -validate can make the SW to notice the problem, but it is not the arg that **creates** the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*... the correct way to reference an external XSD is to use XSD schema with import/include within a wsdl:types element.*

For details, please refer to

[Importing xsd into wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120589/importing-xsd-into-wsdl)

In your case, you are using

```
 *<import namespace="some.xsd"
            location="some.xsd"/>*
```

Following the cited link, why don't you include the `<import namespace=...` element in a  `<types>` element, as also shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12125913/1925356

Comment: So, if I have an operation GetLastTradePrice in PortType, I have to make an import from the xsd file containing the description of the operation?

Comment: Your reference tells about elements. I am talking about operations. We can't say there is no difference because the whole syntax about them is different.

Comment: The xsd we are referencing, contains types and elements, but no bindings and operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Oh, it was totally mine error.** The second section of example 2 of wsdl manual really has only portType without binding. And the xsd file it is importing has no bindings, too (naturally). But the second section is not a service! The service is the third section, that has bindings and imports section 2. So, the service has both portType and binding. **They are not arguments** that demand the `binding` section, it is always demanded for.

I should pay attention to the warning - the file mentioned is not a service yet, there should exist another file for it, that will be a service and will contain include for that file and binding section in it. Or, of course, it could contain both `portType` and `binding` in one file.