# Wsdl target namespace same as imported schema

Tags: xsd, schema, tibco-business-works

I have a WSDL provided by a target system which has some schemas defined as inline on the 'wsdl:types' section, but one of the schema has same target namespace as the WSDL.

Target system also has provided me the associated schemas as .xsd. Now I want to remove the schemas from concrete WSDL and refer the .xsd provided but I am confused whether to use import or include.

I am using Tibco BW to invoke the servicr(XML based).please let me know if I should use import or include.

Comment: I think this thread will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120589/importing-xsd-into-wsdl

Comment: I believe the issue has been resolved and it was not due to the namespace. I used import and it works fine.  Looks like Targetnamespace of WSDL and the schemas inside them are treated differently and there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: Note: ensure that  you have added elementFormDefault="qualified" at the schema to ensure that namespace is applicalbe to all the elements by default explicitly